# Google Rest API does not work on Xamarin forms IOS simulator

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Googgle Api (search place) on my app.  It is working for Android but not for IOS.

On Android I have my json response but on IOS I have nothing

How can I make it work on IOS  ?

I have also tried [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) but without success

Here is my code :

```
     var URL= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?";
            string urlParameters = "?location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&radius=" + Myradius + "&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);


            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameters);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                // do something 
           }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "does not work" is not useful description of the problem.  Does it throw an error or exception?  Does it timeout?  Does it just hang?  Do you get an HTTP response code?  Have you rules out basic networking issues?

Comment: @Jason  On Android I have my json response but on IOS I have nothing. There is no error throw

Comment: "Have you rules out basic networking issues" how can i do it ?

Comment: can you reach the url using your device's browser?  Have you looked at the log for any relevant messages?

Comment: @Jason  Yes I can reach "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json ?" and I have the same aswner as in my pc

Comment: It should not return nothing. Can you please add a try-catch block in             `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameters);` to check if there is any errors. Add a breakpoint there to check if there is any response.